# How to change user in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using an API into a Yii2 app, and so `Yii::$app->user` is null.

Can I manually set `Yii::$app->user`?

All exmaples I have foun involved editing a user, not setting a user.

Comment: You mean that you want login a user ??

Comment: @scaisEdge  Yes I suppose that's what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want log an user you could try getting and identity this way and log the user

```
  / find a user identity with the specified username.
  // note that you may want to check the password if needed

  $identity = User::find()-where(['username' => $username])->one();

  // logs in the user
  Yii::$app->user->login($identity);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

Comment: Way too easy. I thought I had to provide user/password in order to login a user so I ignored this approach. This works perfectly.

Comment: the password  is provided  by identity  .. when you get the User::

Answer (score 1):

You might need to configure the 'user' component in your API app config first. Like so:

```
'components'    => [
    // ...
    'user'      => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
    ],
    // ...
],
```